# Why can't i see my home page in Heroku (with Nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack, routes, webpack-dev-server

This is my project: https://github.com/dade1987/StockPricePrediction

I deployed it in Heroku but i can't see my homepage on this link: https://price-predictor-eu.herokuapp.com/

I see it locally.

Heroku says:

```
2020-06-27T10:33:17.545687+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=price-predictor-eu.herokuapp.com request_id=be6efc89-ba70-4ba8-bb4e-26b85ccce869 fwd="151.36.107.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

I tried to do it too:

```
webpack-dev-server route

✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: 6575b1f5bc373f461724

Version: webpack 4.28.4

Time: 5599ms

Built at: 06/27/2020 2:53:13 PM

 1 asset

Entrypoint main = bundle.js

 [0] (webpack)-dev-server/client/clients/SockJSClient.js 4.06 KiB {0} [built]

 [2] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/log.js 964 bytes {0} [built]

 [3] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 route 40 bytes {0} [built]

 [4] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 4.29 KiB {0} [built]

 [5] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]

 [6] ./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]

 [7] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.53 KiB {0} [built]

[10] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.51 KiB {0} [built]

[11] ./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js 4.16 KiB {0} [built]

[12] ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/index.js 449 bytes {0} [built]

[16] ./node_modules/loglevel/lib/loglevel.js 8.41 KiB {0} [built]

[17] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js 402 bytes {0} [built]

[18] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js 1.59 KiB {0} [built]

[21] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js 2.91 KiB {0} [built]

[30] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {0} [built]

    + 17 hidden modules



ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'route' in '/app'



ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 route

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'route' in '/app'

 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 route main[1]
```

Where is my error? I am not very expert in node.

Thank you

Comment: Please read [ask]. Questions here should be self-contained; we shouldn't have to go off-site just to understand what you're asking.

Comment: In any case, it looks like you're trying to do a bunch of training. How long does this take on your local machine? Heroku has a 30 second timeout, and even if it didn't, most of what I saw there shouldn't be happening as part of a web request.

Comment: Yes, but this operation uses a socket server listener to do it. I can't see the default home page. I don't know where to look or how to debug.

Comment: On a quick scan I didn't see a default home page in your code, and back to my first comment we're not going to spend time digging through an off-site repo to find it. Please [edit] your question and include the relevant code for your index view there.

Comment: Yes. I think it's defined in webpack. I don't know what is the relevant code for this

Comment: No, it should be in your code. You should be handling requests to `/`.

Comment: I have not, but it works on my localhost

Comment: Heroku has a particular way of operating. You need to bind to the port it gives you, and listen for requests. If your code doesn't do that, it won't work on Heroku. It's irrelevant that it works on our local machine.

Comment: And you shouldn't be using `webpack-dev-server` in production. As its name suggests, it's a _development_ tool. That might even be part of the problem. Typically you'd run something like `node app.js`, and that's it.